# Trouble understanding a given circuit for an LDR pulse sensor

Tags: transistors, pulse, kirchhoffs-laws, arduino-uno, ldr

I'm a second year physics student, part of a group, and we're trying to build a pulse monitor following [this](https://www.instructables.com/Homebrew-Arduino-Pulse-Monitor-Visualize-Your-Hear/) guide. This is the schematic I'm having trouble to understand:

[image: Circuit Schematic]

I have basic knowledge of working with Kirchoff Laws, but this is my first time working with transistors.

1. I assume the transistors are there to amplify the signal variation of the LDR. How do they do that?

From what I understood from my research about these transistors, there is a 0.7V drop between base and emitter, and base current is multiplied by a constant to determine collector current. I tried using these to calculate an expression for the voltage measured in the analog pin in function of the LDR resistance, to understand the effect, but I did not get anywhere decent. I want to understand why the circuit was designed like this (unfortunately the guide does not explain that), so that we can troubleshoot easily and change things up if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I expanded my answer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Asking how transistors work is probably not a good fit for this site. There are plenty of google resources about this and that would be a better intro to this book-long subject. Yes, I know your circuit is simple but you'd still need to read one-third of the book-long subject given that nobody knows anything about your ability to learn and your basic starting point.

Comment: A too-simple circuit, whose output depends *very much* on the source-light intensity....too much light keeps the output LED constant **off**...too little light keeps the output LED constant **on**.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume the transistors are there to amplify the signal variation of the LDR. How do they do that?

To a first approximation, think of the transistor as having two current flows, one from base to emitter, the other from collector to emitter. (Yes, I know that sounds backwards, but in electronics, instead of thinking about electron flow, we think of flow as going from positive to negative. Just accept that. :-) ). Anyway, the collector current (simplified) is controlled by the base current. The ratio between these currents is called \$\beta\$, and a value of 100 is a good guess.

One other fact you need to know before you can apply Kirchoff's laws. There is a voltage drop of somewhere around 0.65V between the base of the transistor and the emitter. The exact value changes with temperature and current, but if you use 0.6-0.7 you will be in the ball park. You need to know this because there are resistances in parallel with the base-emitter path in your circuit.

From there, you may be able to apply Kirchoff's laws. Try two different values for the resistance of your LDR and see what that gives you.

> From what I understood from my research about these transistors, there is a 0.7V drop between base and emitter, and base current is multiplied by a constant to determine collector current.

Yes

> I tried using these to calculate an expression for the voltage measured in the analog pin in function of the LDR resistance, to understand the effect, but I did not get anywhere decent.

Try first solving for just the battery, LDR, R3 and the base-emitter path of Q1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFIlRv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then multiply the base current you get by \$\beta\$ (approx. 100) and see if you can solve the rest.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer, it helped :D

For the latter simpler circuit I get that the base current is (V1-0.7)/LDR1-0.7/R3. I will call this I1 from now on.

Using the same logic for the rest of the circuit, I get that the base current on Q2 will be (V1-0.7)/R1- *I1. I will call this I2 from now on.

The voltage reading at A0 should be voltage drop across Q2 (collector and emitter), which is V1 minus the voltage drop at the LED and R2. Voltage drop at R2 is R2*I2*.

All together, assuming =100, R3=1K, V_LED=2V, this gives me values of voltage in the thousands

Comment: My fault for not explaining more thoroughly. What happens if (V1-0.7)/LDR1 is less than 0.7/R3? If you don't know the answer, I will tell you.

Comment: I would assume no current would pass between collector and emitter

Comment: Right. Nor wil any current flow between base and emitter (except a tiny leakage current in both cases that we will ignore for now.) The base-emitter junction is a regular diode, and basically only allows current in one direction. When current doesn't flow through this junction, the voltage across it can be anywhere between 0 and 0.7 volts. This is called transistor cutoff. There is an opposite situation when the voltage from collector to emitter falls below 0.7v. That situation is called saturation. The collector current no longer follows the base current times \$\beta\$ but "maxes out".

Comment: It isn't a hard "maxing out", but  in normal operation, the voltage from collector to emitter (\$V_{ce}\$) will never fall below about 0.2 volts no matter how much base current there is. With these bits of additional knowledge, you will be able to analyse the circuit without getting ridiculous voltages or currents.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I’m going to look into it